# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter in Class

Tags: c#, syntax-error

I made this snippet of code that uses classes to withdraw information as `objects`. I am still very rookie to `Class` and `Object programming` so I tend to get errors. Now I have a problem I absolutely do not understand. I have tried the almighty Google, replacing parts of code with different operators and asking my fellow programmer friends. Nobody seems to have a clue what is going on.

The problem happens in the `CompareBooks` method, and it keeps telling me that I am missing a `formal parameter`. Somebody had recommended to use `:base` in the method, but it only created 2 more errors.

```
namespace ClassProgram
{
    class Book
    {
        public string name;
        public int id;
        public float price;

        public void PrintBookInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Book Name: " + this.name);
            Console.WriteLine("Book Id: " + this.id);
            Console.WriteLine("Book Price: " + this.price + " dollars");
        }

        public void CompareBooks(Book book1)
        {
            if (this.price > book1.price)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.name + " is more expensive than " + book1.name);
            }
        }

        class MainProgram
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Book book = new Book();
                book.name = "C# For Newbies";
                book.id = 01;
                book.price = 10;
                book.PrintBookInfo();
                book.CompareBooks();
                Book book1 = new Book();
                book1.name = "Lord Of The Rings";
                book1.id = 02;
                book1.price = 5;
                book1.PrintBookInfo();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call, your `book.CompareBooks();` does not have `Book` object as parameter input. Compare this with your signature:

```
public void CompareBooks(Book book1) //the Book object is required in the input
```

Thus you got the error. "Formal parameter" means **a-must** parameter (as compared to syntatical sugar [optional-parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) in C#). That means you have to put something in the input parameters of the method to call it.

Suppose in your `MainProgram` it is run like this:

```
Book book = new Book();
book.name = "C# For Newbies";
book.id = 01;
book.price = 10;
book.PrintBookInfo();
Book book1 = new Book();
book1.name = "Lord Of The Rings";
book1.id = 02;
book1.price = 5;
book1.PrintBookInfo();
book.CompareBooks(book1); //note that this has input now
```

Then your code should be okay

Comment: The fact that you create a variable named 'book1' in your main function does not in any way make it available as a parameter named 'book1' in the book object. I'd rename the function to "CompareTo" so you'd get book.CompareTo(otherBook)

Comment: This solved my problem. I did not find any advice on this input parameter before. Now it compares the books and prints "C# For Newbies is more expensive than Lord Of The Rings." Thank you! @Ian

Selected as the best answer as you elaborated the most and this helps me in further learning of C#!

Comment: @Mikex64 no problem. ;) glad that I can be of any help in your learning.

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide any information on to which book your first one should be compared. I suppose you ment something like this:

```
Book book = new Book();
book.name = "C# For Newbies";
book.id = 01;
book.price = 10;
book.PrintBookInfo();

Book book1 = new Book();
book1.name = "Lord Of The Rings";
book1.id = 02;
book1.price = 5;
book1.PrintBookInfo();

book.CompareBooks(book1);
```